# ASP.NET Core: Finding a View - works in IIS Express debug but not in Kestrel 'published'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've spent the afternoon googling and can't find anything that matches my problem.

I'm using ASP.NET Core 1.0.0 for a simple web site.  All behaves fine when debugging in IIS-Express in VS 2015. But when I publish the site (either using the built-in VS2015 tools or manually using 'dotnet publish') I get a "The View 'xxx" was not found' error every time I try and access a page.

Here's the code:

Controller:

```
  public class CalcController : Controller
  {
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    ... etc ....

   }
```

and here's a screenshot of my Views folder:

[image]

This all works absolutely fine in IIS Express within VS 2015.  But when I publish and try running the published code I get this:

[image]

FWIW - I can serve static pages and js, css etc without any problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure the views are being included in the publish output? ie you see the Views folder in the published output and it has the correct files?

Comment: @joe - the published output is a single dll (plus all the MS dlls).  AFAICS that's what's supposed to happen? The css/js files are being returned correctly from within that dll somewhere so I assume the rest is in there somewhere?

Comment: no Views generally need to be included in the published output as does the wwwroot folder and js and css, I just posted an answer with details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the project.json file of your web app, you need to include the views (and other needed files) in the publish options like this so that they are included in the published output:

```
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
        "wwwroot",
        "Views",
        "Areas/**/Views",
        "sitefiles",
        "dp_keys",
        "nodb_storage",
        "appsettings.json",
        "web.config"
    ]
},
```

as far as I know views are not pre-compiled, at least by default though there may be some possible way to do that.

it is also possible to embed views into the dll like this:

```
 "buildOptions": {
    "embed": [ "Views/**", "js/**", "css/**" ]
},
```

which I do in class library projects that have controllers, but then you need to have startup logic to make it find those embedded views

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()
    .AddRazorOptions(options =>
    {  
        options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(
            typeof(SiteManager).GetTypeInfo().Assembly,
            "cloudscribe.Core.Web"
        ));
    })
    ;
```

Comment: note that embedding js and css is not sufficient to make them requestable, I use a controller to render the embedded js and css

Comment: That did it! Your explanation makes good sense...  I added "Views" to project.json and all is well.